# Eclipse+Pydev Unexpected error setting up the debugger

Tags: eclipse, pydev

Hello，I want to debug with PyDev in Eclipse,but it give me a hint,"Launching xxx.py has encountered a problem.Unexpected error setting up the debugger" and the detailed imformation is "select failed".However,it can still run as usual with "Ctrl+F11".
By the way,I have reinstall the Eclipse and PyDev for some times,but is doesn't work

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please open the Eclipse error long and add the information from there to your question (see: http://pydev.org/faq.html#PyDevFAQ-HowdoIReportaBUG%3F for details on finding the error log).